# Kubernetes job deleted before running to completion

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We are in process of migrating init-container to Kubernetes job. I have created job with below job.yaml with init-container image. init-container restarts continuously till it runs to completion but Kubernetes job restarts for 5 times and then job pod gets removed automatically. I want k8s job to retry with back-off continuously till it runs to completion like init-container pod. How can I achieve this?

job.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-init-job"
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: disabled
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,pre-delete
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}-init-service-account
      containers:
        - name: app-installer
          image: some image
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - echo Hello executing k8s init-container
          securityContext:
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I could see restarted till 5 attempts

```
% kubectl get pods -n testnamespace
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
test-595b84fddf-qlsjf    2/2     Running            0               5m59s
test-init-job--1-dlpmw   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (2m34s ago)   5m59s
```

Job pod disappears after 5 attempts

```
% kubectl get pods -n testnamespace

NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
test-595b84fddf-qlsjf    2/2     Running            0               5m59s
```

Comment: The Job you show should run to completion once; I'm not sure when it would restart, or how it could stay running for six minutes.  Have you looked at the [Kubernetes Job documentation on Pod and container failures](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#handling-pod-and-container-failures)?

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link shared by @Mikekilic

There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set .spec.backoffLimit to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6. Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s ...) capped at six minutes.

The number of retries is calculated in two ways:

1. The number of Pods with .status.phase = "Failed".
2. When using restartPolicy = "OnFailure", the number of retries in all the containers of Pods with .status.phase equal to Pending or Running.
   If either of the calculations reaches the .spec.backoffLimit, the Job is considered failed.